# How can I use get_next_by_FOO() in django?

Tags: python, django, blogs

I am building blog website and trying to put `next` and `prev` buttons for next post and previous post respectively.

In the official document, it explains `get_next_by_FOO(**kwargs)` and `where FOO is the name of the field. This returns the next and previous object with respect to the date field`.

So my models.py and views.py are following.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]
```

views.py

```
def post_detail(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    the_next = instance.get_next_by_title()
    context ={
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "the_next" : the_next,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

Do I misunderstand its concept?? If I do, how can I deal with it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

`get_next_by_FOO` works on the date field, think of it like "get me the next record ordered by the date (or datetime) field *FOO*".

So *FOO* is the name of a date or datetime field.

In your model, you can say "get me the next record based on timestamp", and this would be `get_next_by_timestamp()` or "get me the next record based on the updated date", and this would be `get_next_by_updated()`.

Comment: I thought I could assign any fields because I thought they are automatically connect to datetime field since they are in same class. I fixed my `views.py` and edited my template like `<a href={{ the_next }}> Next </a>` Then I clicked this one, but it gave me 404 page not found error. Do you think I have to set URL?? Thank you!

Comment: Yes of course, you have to map it via urls to a view.

Comment: It is getting more exciting!! Thank you so much for help me!