# Using get_next_by_FOO and get_previous_by_FOO in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am building off of the question listed here: [How can I use get_next_by_FOO() in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070840/how-can-i-use-get-next-by-foo-in-django)

I have altered the code for my project (see below), but when I click on "next" to hyperlink to the next object in my Picture model the same page only reloads. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Models.py**

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('picture-detail', kwargs={ 'pk': self.pk })
```

**views.py**

```
class PictureDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Picture

def picture_detail(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Picture, id=id)
    the_next = instance.get_next_by_date_posted()   
    context = {
        'name': instance.name,
        'instance': instance,
        'the_next': the_next,
    }
    return render(request, 'gallery/picture_detail.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='gallery-home'),
path('picture/', PictureListView.as_view(), name='gallery-picture'),
path('picture/<int:pk>/', PictureDetailView.as_view(), name='picture-detail'),
]
```

**picture_detail.html**

```
<a href="{{ the_next }}"> Next </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to obtain the `get_absolute_url` of the next instance. `the_next` is only a `Picture`, not its link, so:

```
<a href="{{ the_next.get_absolute_url }}">Next</a>
```